# counting unique values with it's associated count and total number of values

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, conditional-statements

It may be simple but I am struck now. I have an array

```
items=["shelter","tent","shelter","injured","displaced","displaced"]
```

and it's values with it's respective value as

```
magnitude = [5,12,6,9,13,2]
```

Now,the task is to add item_name with it's respective total magnitude and number of its occurrence as:

> shelter for 11 people,
>   tent for 12 people,
>   9 people injured,
>   15 people displaced

I tried with some loops and conditions but I am tired now. Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Please at least show us your attempts.

Comment: I have different kind of object so it's hard to represent here and also I do not have reputation to post an image. Wait I will create a fiddle for that.

Comment: Well, it's even harder to figure out what your problem is…

Comment: I tried previously for number of unique items and it's occurence by http://jsfiddle.net/shumanbaral/9dLts1Lb/ but I do not know how to link with magnitude i.e. adding every items magnitude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start by creating an object like this:

```
var map = {};
for (var i = 0, count = items.length; i < count; i++) {
    map[items[i]] = (map[items[i]] || 0) + magnitude[i];
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4hh4zmwh/)

You can view the values like this:

```
for (var item in map) {
    console.log(item + ': ' + map[item]);
}
```

Or just access them individually, like this:

```
console.log('shelter for ' + map['shelter'] + ' people');
console.log('tent for ' + map['tent'] + ' people');
console.log(map['injured'] + ' people injured');
console.log(map['displaced'] + ' people displaced');
```

Comment: Actually its repeating, the task is to find unique items and adding it's count.  I think you understand what I mean, like
shelter for 11 people (here 11 came by adding 6 and 5 of item shelter )

Comment: @Shuman - What do you mean its repeating. Each item will be in the `map` object a single time, with the total magnitude as its value.

Comment: Here it gives :
shelter for 5 people
tent for 12 people
shelter for 6 people
injured for 9 people
displaced for 13 people
displaced for 2 people
but working with thousands of items I need to do as
shelter for 11 people tent for 12 people...

Comment: Yes yes this is the exactly what I was wanting. A tons of thanks from my side. Have a great time ahead. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want do that you can use $.each, like this:

```
var items=["shelter","tent","shelter","injured","displaced","displaced"] 

var magnitudes = [5,12,6,9,13,2]  

var map = new Map();

$.each(items,function(key,value) {  
     console.log(value);
     var element = map.get(value);
     if(element == undefined)
         element = 0;   
     var element = element + magnitudes[key];
     map.set(value,element);
 })

console.log(map);
```

Here we are looping in items and putting to a map, if we alredy have the value we add te new value to the old.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Actually its repeating, the task is to find unique items and adding it's count.  I think you understand what I mean, like
shelter for 11 people (here 11 came by adding 6 and 5 of item shelter )

Comment: Oh i understand bad the answer, sory. I edit the answer for future users.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
var msgs = {
    shelter: 'shelter for {count} people',
    tent: 'tent for {count} people',
    injured: '{count} people injured',
    displaced: '{count} people displaced'
};

tems = ["shelter", "tent", "shelter", "injured", "displaced", "displaced"];

magnitude = [5, 12, 6, 9, 13, 2];

var tmp = {};

for (var i = 0; i < tems.length; i++) {
    tmp[tems[i]] = (tmp[tems[i]] || 0) + 1;
}
var array = [];
for (var key in tmp) {
    array.push(msgs[key].replace('{count}', tmp[key]))
}
console.log(array)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/b1wc3egz/)